# Using the same *ngFor loops in a template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Reading a book I came across an example that uses the same *ngFor loop twice in the same template. I tried to refactor breaking into nested components and sending down the 'i' variable which didn't work.

The example uses a bootstrap carousel and needs to loop through Categories for both the indicator buttons and the slideshow.

Do you know a better way of writing this that's not repeating the same loop?

```
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#welcome-products"
      *ngFor="let category of slideCategories;let first=first; let i=index"
      attr.data-slide-to="{{i}}" [ngClass]="{active: first}"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Content -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

  <div *ngFor="let category of slideCategories;let first=first"
        class="carousel-item" [ngClass]="{active: first}">
    <db-category-slide
      [category]="category" (select)="selectCategory($event)">
    </db-category-slide>
  </div>
```

This is the template for **db-category-slide**

```
<div class="card">
<img class="card-img-top img-fluid center-block product-item" src="{{category.image}}" alt="{{category.title}}">
<div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">{{category.title}}</h4>
    <p class="card-text">{{category.desc}}</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="browse()">Browse</button>
</div>
</div>
```

The components have the same Input/Output and look like this:

```
@Input() category: Category;
@Output() select: EventEmitter<Category> = new EventEmitter<Category>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Indicators` HTML as below :

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#welcome-products"
      *ngFor="let category of slideCategories;let first=first; let i=index"
      [attr.data-slide-to]="i" [ngClass]="{active: first}"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I'll upvote since that is how we should bind.  But it doesn't fix the issue.  I think because the carousel-indicators Have to be outside of the carousel-inner to work for some reason.